"node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1146" error in react app installing
Getting these errors in console
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1146
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../../package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\adity\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\es6\validate-engines.js
- C:\Users\adity\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\adity\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\adity\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\es6\validate-engines.js:8:49)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\adity\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\es6\\validate-engines.js',        
    'C:\\Users\\adity\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\adity\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v20.12.1

what should i do
Tried : deleting and reinstalling the latest node packages
also tried npm uninstall json-server
and no commands of npm is running in every case the result is same

What did you use to create react app? I would suggest you to try out vite

not working that as well

actually the error was in installing the nodejs if u put it default it will not install the npm u have to select it in newer versions
